# DataGrid's SelectedItems and highlighted rows unsynchronize after deleting row that was selected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have DataGrid with ItemsSource bound to ObservableCollection in ViewModel. DataGrid allows multiple rows to be selected. ViewModel subscribes to an event (from some service) and handling that event includes removing one object from ObservableCollection. If that object was one of selected objects, something weird happens with highlighted rows in DataGrid. I don't know how exactly to explain it, so here is an image

[image].

Here is code that reproduces the problem. Added button on toolbar that removes 3rd selected item, so make sure you select 5+ items before pressing the button.

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyItems { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            MyItems.Add(new MyObject("name" + i, i));
        }
    }
}
```

View (xaml)

```
<Window x:Class="ItemsChangedTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsChangedTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <ToolBar DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="Test" Click="TestButton_Click"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <DataGrid Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind (added button handler to test this behavior)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as MyViewModel).MyItems.Remove(MyDataGrid.SelectedItems[2] as MyObject);
    }
}
```

Model (simple class)

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public MyObject(string name, int age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: from what you re saying, seems that the data grid removes the item and them unselect the the one from the list with the same id. I dont see any problem in your code. If it is a DataGrid bug, i guess you should then manage an ObservableCollection<MyObject> SelectedItems on the view model. And reset the DataGrid ones with yours consistently

Comment: @alessalessio, I get this error when trying to bind SelectedItems - "'SelectedItems' property is read-only and cannot be set from markup."

Answer (score 1):

Add a datagrid refresh and focus after deletion.

```
 private void TestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        (DataContext as MyViewModel).MyItems.Remove(MyDataGrid.SelectedItems[2] as MyObject);
        MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
        MyDataGrid.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: I can't do that, because method that does removing from ObservableCollection (handler for event that comes from another service) is located in ViewModel.

Comment: Relevant part of event handler is `MyItems.Remove(someItem);`
Error happens when someItem is in DataGrid.SelectedItems

Answer (score 0):

Whenever one of selected rows gets removed 2 events are called:

DataGrid.SelectedCellsChanged is called first and in SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems are all cells from row which is AFTER the row that needs to be removed. This row after doesn't need to be in selection, but if it is then it loses the selected row style which in my opinion does not work as expected.

DataGrid.SelectionChanged is called second and in SelectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems contains only row that is about to be removed (works as expected).